# Use serverless function to findById in MongoDB Database via Mongoose, and render result in React form - not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have built an 'edit' page which is attempting to pull an individual object in my MongoDB Database, by using 'findById' in a serverless function hosted by Vercel.

The response data I'm then attempting to use to populate the 'value' of different inputs on this 'edit' page.

However, I'm getting no response from my call (not even an error message, neither in my console or my function logs on Vercel) - the page is loading successfully, but no data is being put into the inputs, they're coming through as blank. I've added a console log for the response, and the details of that are in the edit below.

It's worth noting - the URL is the MongoDB ID for the object that's being called!

I have tried refactoring my code, searching for solutions, going through tutorials, but nothing seems to be working. It's frustrating as I'm just not getting any feedback from my app, so don't know what I'm doing wrong?

If anyone has any feedback on my code, that'd be appreciated. Please let me know if I've missed anything out below.

The 'child' and 'parent' components are just how the page gets navigated to.

My 'route' via React Router:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditDebt} />
```

My MongoDB schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  creditCard: String,
  personalLoan: String,
  provider: String,
  balance: Number,
  limit: Number,
  monthly: Number,
  interest: Number,
  borrowed: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('submitdebts', SubmitDebtSchema);
```

My 'child' component which uses props to fill the link using the response MongoDB ID.

```
<div className="debt-card-edit-container"><a className="debt-card-edit-link" href={`/edit/${props.edit}`}>Edit</a></div>
```

My 'parent' component which fills the prop in using a database call:

```
<IndividualDebtCard edit={debt._id} />
```

My 'fetch' serverless function:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const SubmitDebt = require("./submitDebtSchema");

require("dotenv").config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    
  module.exports = async (req, res) => {
      let id = req.params.id;
      await SubmitDebt.findById(id, function(err, submitdebts) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(req.params.id)
        console.log(submitdebts);
        return res.status(200).json(submitdebts);
      });
  };
```

Finally, and most importantly, my actual 'edit' component in full...

```
    class EditDebt extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
          provider: '',
          balance: '',
          limit: '',
          monthly: '',
          interest: '',
          borrowed: ''
        }
    
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
      }
    
       componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("/api/fetchEditDebt")
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({
              provider: response.data.provider,
              balance: response.data.balance,
              limit: response.data.limit,
              monthly: response.data.monthly,
              interest: response.data.interest,
              borrowed: response.data.borrowed
            })
            console.log(res)
            console.log(this.state.provider)
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    
      onChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
        }
    
      render() {
    
        return (
          <section className="edit-debt-section">
            <div className="edit-debt-container">

    
<input type="text" value={this.state.provider} onChange=.  {this.onChange} />


            </div>
          </section>
        )
      }
    }
```

Sorry about all of the code, and please let me know if I've missed anything which is really important in my question.

Thank you

EDIT: I've removed the 'this.props.match.params.id' and tried re-running my code.. I now get the following error in my back-end:

```
2020-10-23T14:55:25.984Z    71f7b650-1a7d-42c2-953e-ff17edc22cb5    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","    at module.exports (/var/task/api/fetchEditDebt.js:12:23)","    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/task/___now_helpers.js:813:19)","    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)","    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:790:12)","    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined","    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:327:22)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your axios api code with this.

```
axios.get("/api/fetchEditDebt", { params: { id: this.props.match.params.id }})
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          provider: response.data.provider,
          balance: response.data.balance,
          limit: response.data.limit,
          monthly: response.data.monthly,
          interest: response.data.interest,
          borrowed: response.data.borrowed
        })
        console.log(res)
        console.log(this.state.provider)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I solved it a little while ago, but this is basically the solution I used. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add an additional '/' on your request url?

`axios.get("/api/fetchEditDebt/"+this.props.match.params.id)`

Comment: Tried that, no luck. I'm updating my original question with outputs from a couple of console logs.

Comment: Can you ensure you can connect to mongoDB? Also can you log what is the response. the code above i see is loggin res object instead of response.

Comment: Hi - I can connect using that exact setup in other functions in my application for MongoDb, so no problem there! Can you clarify exactly what console log too? I've tried it with console.log(response) and console.log(res), with the same output each time. Cheers.

Comment: Could you expand the data object on the response. I'm not sure that's the one you should be receiving, this problem could be on the backend side of things.

Comment: The data object doesn’t expand! Which is strange. I believe it does on other database calls I make elsewhere, so I think you’re right - it’s the serverless function where the problem seems to be (I think).

Comment: It's returning the index.html which means there's a problem with your API. Can you log submitdebts on your API and do some error handling on your findById code.

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect what you've asked, and added a screenshot. It's simply not working. :(

Comment: Can you show me the log on the backend? You're only showing the front end log.

Comment: There isn’t a backend log.. Unless you’re referring to my Vercel (web host) log, which just shows up completely blank. There isn’t a backend per se, I’m using serverless functions.

Comment: What does this log?
        `console.log(req.params.id)
        console.log(submitdebts);`

Comment: Nothing. Where should I be seeing that appear?

Comment: Hey, I've updated what the console.logs look like - it only shows up as 'id' with being undefined! Any tips?

Comment: Can you add your yaml file?